# I am not able to drop a column in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to split my data set into independent and dependent variables

I want to split my data set in x and y variable so that i can train them

```
df = pd.read_csv('path.csv') 
df.shape
x=df.dropna(["y"])
```

Things that I have tried

```
x=df.dropna(["y"],axis=1)
```

I want to have all the values in x except column y.
I am getting below error

> ValueError: No axis named y for object type

Comment: x=df.drop(["y"],axis=1) :This worked for me

Comment: and also working `y=df["y"].to_frame().reset_index()`? It is wrong.

Comment: I write comment, because here was accepted wrong answer by accident only.

Comment: also 2 hours ago was partly corrected  `x=df.drop(["y"])` to `x=df.drop(["y"], axis=1)`, both was wrong before 2 hours, x and y.

Comment: correct answer is `y = df['y']
x = df.drop("y", axis=1)`, check my second solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```py
y=df["y"].to_frame().reset_index() #to preserve column y in y dataframe
x=df.drop(["y"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `y`:

```
y = df.pop('y')
x = df.copy()
```

Or [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove column `y`:

```
y = df['y']
x = df.drop("y", axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[4,5,2],
         'b':[7,8,9],
         'c':[1,3,5],
         'y':[5,3,4],
})

y = df.pop('y')
x = df.copy()
print (x)
   a  b  c
0  4  7  1
1  5  8  3
2  2  9  5

print (y)
0    5
1    3
2    4
Name: y, dtype: int64
```